# JMockIt Mock not being applied using Faking : Mocking parents of mocked classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

Ok... I have an answer... see below. Thanks to everyone that helped. I have updated the title as well to better reflect the issues.

---

UPDATE2: The constructor of the parent class of ClassNotUnderTest (which has parameters) is being called with null parameters, which in turn calls it's parent with the same null parameters, which ends up causing a null exception.

I have tried:

Making mocks of both parents, with only the constructor mocked and used one or both of them when trying out the test. The MockClassNotUnderTest still calls the real constructors.

I tried using the @Mocked annotation in the parameter list for the test method, because I don't really want anything back from those parents... Nope. Causes some other error I don't understand.

I tried putting a super(someParams) call in my $init function, but that won't compile.

HEEEEELLLLLPPPPP!!!!

---

UPDATE:

Ok, the root of my problem is not the implementation as shown below, but with the mock itself. When the MockClassNotUnderTest makes it's constructor call, it is calling the constructor of the real parent of ClassNotUnderTest. I tried also mocking ParentofClassNotUnderTest, but that just caused NullPointerExceptions... sigh. Still searching, I will post updates as they occur. Any suggestions are welcome.

---

I am fairly new to JMockIt, but my Java skills are not bad. I am trying to mock a dependency class of the class under test. It appears that the either the real method is being called, or maybe it is the super class (more likely). So any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Now I know some might comment on how I am setting the error parameter, and how that might be applied etc, and I welcome the comments, but the main problem is that this code is not being mocked properly/at all as far as I can see.

To answer a few questions up front... Yes I searched here, and yes I reviewed the tutorials/documentation at the JMockIt website... had both open as I wrote the code in the first place.

I have several similar situations to resolve, so any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Something like this:

```
public ClassUnderTest {

    public someMethodUnderTest (){
        <blah blah setup stuff>
        try{
            somevar = new ClassNotUnderTest(someParamA, someParamB, someParamC);
        } catch(SomeExceptionA sea) {
            System.out.printline("Go boom");
        } <more catches here>
    }
}
```

My test/mock classes are as follows (JUnit4/JMockIt):

```
public class TestClassUnderTest{

    ClassUnderTest cut;

    <Before method and constructor with some setup code for cut>

    @Test public void test_someMethodUnderTest(){
        MockClassNotUnderTest notUnderTest = new MockClassNotUnderTest();
        notUnderTest.error = 1;

        try{
            testResults = cut.someMethodUnderTest();
        } catch( SomeExceptionA sea) {
            <test that it went boom>
        }
    }

    public class MockClassNotUnderTest extends MockUp<ClassNotUnderTest> {

        public int error = 4;

        @Mock
        public void $init(someParamA, someParamB, someParamC) throws SomeExceptionA, SomeExceptionB, SomeExceptionC {

            if(error == 0) { thrown new SomeExeptionA(); }
            else if(error == 1) { thrown new SomeExeptionB(); }
            else if(error == 2) { thrown new SomeExeptionC(); }
            else { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My pseudo coding/ markup skills suck... Just in case it is not clear, the mock is a sub-class of the test class.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for fixing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>My expectation would be that the `new MockClassNotUnderTest()` you are initializing in the test method does *not* share state with the `new ClassNotUnderTest()` that you are initializing in the production code.</strike>

Try making your `error` a `static` field, so that it is shared across objects being faked.

I have written a sample test case showing that your comment below is correct. I cannot replicate your problem unless you post real code... Here is my test:

```
public class FakeTest {

    public static class Foo {
        public void doSomething() {
            try {
                Bar b = new Bar(73);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Got a " + t.getClass());
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Bar {
        private Integer param;
        public Bar(Integer parameter) {
            System.out.println("Got a real bar with param " + parameter); 
            this.param = parameter;
        }
    }

    public static class MockBar extends MockUp<Bar> {
        public int error = 4;

        @Mock
        public void $init(Integer parameter) {
            System.out.println("Initing fake with parameter " + parameter);
            if (error==1) {
                throw new IllegalAccessError();
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void fakeTest() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Testing...");
        MockBar mb = new MockBar();
        mb.error=1;

        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.doSomething();
    }
}
```

The output, as you would expect, is

```
Testing...
Initing fake with parameter 73
Got a class java.lang.IllegalAccessError
```

Comment: This is where the documentation starts to lose me. That was my thought too, until I read that "all future instantiations" of the mocked object would use the mock until you tell it otherwise. So... does that mean all future objects in the test function? How would I get my mock into my methodUnderTest?

Comment: @ConfusedinCapeCanaveral I cannot replicate your problem--I finally took the time to try, and my test worked without making `error` a static field. I've edited my answer with what I did.

Comment: @ConfusedinCapeCanaveral "All future instantiations" depends on the context. If you declared the mock at the class level, the mock will apply to all tests. If you declare it at the test method level, as you did, it will apply only to that test.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, and accurately (except the static base classes) represents what I have going here. So I did some more poking about and found that it is not the mocked class that is causing a problem, but the parent class constructor (2 times removed.) Can I manually call the super class constructor to head this off? ... thinking ... ... Maybe use the it parameter to call the real constructor, then throw my error anyway? hmm.... No that won't work... can't call a constructor on the it parameter.... Maybe something in JMockit docs to cover this. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: @ConfusedinCapeCanaveral Yeah, I should have noted that I used static nested classes so the whole demo could be self-contained. It applies regardless of whether they are nested or not.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this as a part II to the answer provided above.

What is provided there will successfully mock out a constructor. The root of my issue lay in the fact that my original MockClassNotUnderTest was calling the constructor of the REAL parent of ClassNotUnderTest. In faking this was not completely unexpected, so I made a mock of the parent... which the mock never called.

My original setup of the mocks (the MockBar mb = new MockBar() above) would have a line above it to setup the parent mock, which looked exactly the same, but with a different name. So I might have:

```
MockBarParent mbp = new MockBarParent();
MockBar mb = new MockBar();
mb.error = 1;
```

This did not work obviously... here's what did work:

```
Mockit.setUpMock(new MockBarParent());
MockBar mb = new MockBar();
mb.error = 1;
```

Now as for the why, I am not sure, but I can tell you this is how you setup a static mock.

One final word. These mocks will stay in memory when you do this. Be sure to call Mockit.tearDownMocks() before leaving the test function or it will persist into other tests. JUnit does not run tests in order, so this can cause all kinds of fun errors.

THANKS AGAIN FOR THE HELP!!!!! @dcsohl and Nicolas

Comment: One last note. I eventually moved to just mocking the parent and letting MockBar run as normal... I am testing exceptions here and super is the first call. I just threw the exceptions in the parent mock instead. The parent mock constructor does NOT have to throw the same exceptions as the real parent mock. I therefore consolidated all the exceptions that the various children threw into the parent mock constructor and let that one stand for all of them... I then did not need to use this static initialization with the Mockit.setUpMock and instead did exactly like shown in the first answer.

Comment: Note that the `Mockit` class has been removed from JMockit years ago... so you are probably using a very outdated version (and its outdated documentation).